# Hybris Solr Indexing throws Nullpointer exception

Tags: indexing, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am executing full solr indexing in Hybris, and i am getting the below error. Can anyone help.

Indexing failed.

16.03.2021 13:43:42: ERROR: Caught throwable null java.lang.NullPointerException at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.AbstractSolrSearchProvider.createSynonyms(AbstractSolrSearchProvider.java:382) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.AbstractSolrSearchProvider.createSynonymsForLanguages(AbstractSolrSearchProvider.java:363) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.SolrStandaloneSearchProvider.exportConfig(SolrStandaloneSearchProvider.java:266) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.listeners.IndexerOperationListener.afterPrepareContext(IndexerOperationListener.java:87) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexerContextFactory.executeAfterPrepareListeners(DefaultIndexerContextFactory.java:168) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexerContextFactory.prepareContext(DefaultIndexerContextFactory.java:97) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.AbstractIndexerStrategy.doExecute(AbstractIndexerStrategy.java:147) at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.AbstractIndexerStrategy.execute(AbstractIndexerStrategy.java:116) ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks some synonyms configuration not correct. You can try it in debug mode or you can check the code and of there is some logging function you can enable it in hac for getting more detail.